# ManimGL doesn't render the SVGMobject properly, why is that? All of my other scenes work beautifuly

Tags: python, manim

[image]I used 3B1B's pi creature code to render a pi creature but unfortunately the svg is distorted, any ideas why?
I have imported all of the files correctly, here is a snippet.

```py
        morty = Mortimer()
        morty.to_corner(DR)
        self.play(PiCreatureSays(
            morty, TexText("Outstanding\\\\channel"), target_mode="hooray",
            bubble_kwargs={"height": 3, "width": 4}
        ))
        self.play(Blink(morty))
        self.wait()



        
        self.play(RemovePiCreatureBubble(morty))
        
        
        
        
        self.play(Blink(morty))
        self.wait(1)
        self.play(Blink(morty))
        self.wait(1)
        self.play(Blink(morty))
        self.wait(1)
        self.play(Blink(morty))
        self.wait(1)
        self.play(Blink(morty))
        self.wait(1)
        self.play(Blink(morty))
        self.wait(1)
        self.play(Blink(morty))
        self.wait(1)[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: Maybe try asking this in the manim community discord server, you're more likely to get answers there.